# Find changed object in JavaFX ObservableArrayList

Tags: object, javafx, listener, observable

It took me way too long to set up a listener on one property of the objects in my Observablelist and add a listener to it.

```
 ObservableList<Track> observableResult = FXCollections.observableArrayList((Track tr)-> new Observable[]{tr.selectedProperty()});
                    observableResult.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Track>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(Change<? extends Track> c) {
                            c.next();
                            for(Track k : c.getAddedSubList()){
                                System.out.println(k.getTrackName());
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

But I can't seem to be able to locate the actual object the change has been made to. The Change class only appears to support added and removed members, which don't get triggered by the actual changes inside them.

I have a workaround for this, just calling another method that would loop trough the entire ObservableArrayList and get for example, only the selected items, but that gets pretty expensive after I have a couple of thousand objects. Finding the source members that got changed would allow me to just push them to another array and save a bunch of overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `getFrom()` on the change to get the index of the changed item. I don't think there's a way to actually figure out which property changed (if you have more than one property listed in the extractor) or get the old value, but maybe this is enough.

If you need more, you could consider registering your own listeners with the list to track, which would be tricky but not impossible.

Here's an SSCCE demonstrating the `getFrom()` call:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class ListChangeListenerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObservableList<Item> itemList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(item -> new Observable[]{item.valueProperty()});
        itemList.addListener((Change<? extends Item> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                    int index = c.getFrom();
                    System.out.println("Updated item at "+index+" new value is "+itemList.get(index).getValue());
                }
            }
        });
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000).mapToObj(Item::new).forEach(itemList::add);

        Random rng = new Random();
        itemList.get(rng.nextInt(itemList.size())).setValue(rng.nextInt(10000));

    }

    public static class Item {
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        public Item(int value) {
            setValue(value);
        }
        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }



    }

}
```

Here's a version that manages the listeners on the property manually. Note that

1. This doesn't use an extractor on the list
2. The property in the `Item` bean is constructed passing a reference to the bean that owns the property. This allows the listener on the property to get a reference to the `Item` (via a bit of ugly downcasting)

This gives a bit more flexibility; e.g. if you wanted to check modifications on multiple properties and perform different actions, this would allow this. As you can see, the listener can also access the old value.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class ListChangeListenerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        ChangeListener<Number> valueListener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            Item item = (Item) ((Property<?>) obs).getBean();
            System.out.println("Value for "+item+" changed from " + oldValue + " to "+newValue);
        };

        ObservableList<Item> itemList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        itemList.addListener((Change<? extends Item> change) -> {
            while (change.next()) {
                if (change.wasAdded()) {
                    for (Item item : change.getAddedSubList()) {
                        item.valueProperty().addListener(valueListener);
                    }
                }
                if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                    for (Item item : change.getRemoved()) {
                        item.valueProperty().removeListener(valueListener);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000).mapToObj(Item::new).forEach(itemList::add);

        Random rng = new Random();
        itemList.get(rng.nextInt(itemList.size())).setValue(rng.nextInt(10000));

    }

    public static class Item {
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "value");
        private final String id ;
        public Item(int value) {
            id = "Item "+value ;
            setValue(value);
        }
        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return id ;
        }

    }

}
```

Finally, if you want to account for "bulk" updates, you need to implement `ObservableList` yourself. You can do this by subclassing `ModifiableObservableListBase`, and the basic idea is pretty straightforward. The implementation is made a bit tedious by having to create the `Change` object representing the update, but it's not too bad. Here's an example that allows updating a contiguous range:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase;

public class UpdatingObservableList<T> extends ModifiableObservableListBase<T> {

    private final List<T> list ;

    public UpdatingObservableList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list ;
    }

    public UpdatingObservableList() {
        this(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public void updateSublist(int start, int end, Consumer<T> updater) {
        if (start < 0) throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Start ("+start+") cannot be < 0");
        if (end < start) throw new IllegalArgumentException("End ("+end+") cannot be less than start ("+start+")");
        if (end > size()) throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("End ("+end+") cannot be greater than list size ("+size()+")");

        for (T element : list.subList(start, end)) {
            updater.accept(element);
        }

        fireChange(createUpdate(start, end));
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return list.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doAdd(int index, T element) {
        list.add(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    protected T doSet(int index, T element) {
        return list.set(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    protected T doRemove(int index) {
        return list.remove(index);
    }

    private Change<T> createUpdate(int start, int end) {
        return new Change<T>(this) {

            private boolean initialState = true ;

            @Override
            public boolean next() {
                if (initialState) {
                    initialState = false ;
                    return true ;
                }
                return false ;
            }

            @Override
            public void reset() {
                initialState = true ;
            }

            @Override
            public int getFrom() {
                checkState();
                return start ;
            }

            @Override
            public int getTo() {
                checkState();
                return end ;
            }

            @Override
            public List<T> getAddedSubList() {
                checkState();
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }

            @Override
            public List<T> getRemoved() {
                checkState();
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }

            @Override
            protected int[] getPermutation() {
                checkState();
                return new int[0];
            }

            @Override
            public boolean wasAdded() {
                checkState();
                return false ;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean wasRemoved() {
                checkState();
                return false ;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean wasUpdated() {
                return true ;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean wasPermutated() {
                checkState();
                return false ;
            }

            @Override
            public int getRemovedSize() {
                checkState();
                return 0 ;
            }

            @Override
            public int getAddedSize() {
                checkState();
                return 0 ;
            }

            private void checkState() {
                if (initialState) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Must call Change.next()");
                }
            }

        };
    }
}
```

and here's a version of the test class that uses this. Note that the update is performed via the list:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;

public class ListChangeListenerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        UpdatingObservableList<Item> itemList = new UpdatingObservableList<Item>();
        itemList.addListener((Change<? extends Item> change) -> {
            while (change.next()) {
                if (change.wasUpdated()) {
                    for (int i = change.getFrom() ; i < change.getTo() ; i++) {
                        System.out.println(itemList.get(i) + " updated - new value: "+itemList.get(i).getValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000).mapToObj(Item::new).forEach(itemList::add);

        Random rng = new Random();
        int start = rng.nextInt(itemList.size());
        int end = Math.min(itemList.size(), start + 1 + rng.nextInt(15));
        itemList.updateSublist(start, end, item -> item.setValue(rng.nextInt(10000)));
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "value");
        private final String id ;
        public Item(int value) {
            id = "Item "+value ;
            setValue(value);
        }
        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return id ;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can I somehow get multiple items at once? For example when using a checkbox to check more than one at once?

Comment: I don't think so. I think that the list only fires the update notifications when each individual property changes (it has no way of knowing more changes are imminent). You would probably have to implement `ObservableList` yourself to do this...

Comment: Perhaps I can somehow utilize c.next(), but only if it has hasNext

Comment: How though? Think about what is going on behind the scenes. If you use a checkbox to "check more than one at once", presumably all you are doing is modifying the `selected` property of multiple items in a loop. The only possible implementation of the list is to observe the selected properties of the individual items (like my second example), and translate changes in those to update events on the list. Since you're changing each `selectedProperty` one at a time in a loop, the list has no idea when the changes are finished. You would have to have functionality built into the list.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'm looping anyway when selecting multiple objects so I might as well add them to the second list. But in theory it should work only with the code you provided

Comment: It's an interesting idea though: create an `ObservableList<T>` with a "bulkUpdate" method. Something like `public void updateSublist(int start, int end, Consumer<T> updater);` which would generate a single `ListChangeListener.Change<T>`. Should be possible...

Comment: I guess it would be easier to actually make it myself. I'll try it tomorrow. Next issue after this one is making a column in TableView that would display different images based on the boolean value of the elements. CellFactory is really strange so I'll probably be posting a new question tomorrow.

Comment: That last part is pretty easy :)

Comment: Ok, added a list implementation that allows bulk updates. You could do a "select all" by calling `list.updateSublist(0, list.size(), item -> item.setSelected(true));`. Note that it will consider *all* items to be "updated" even if they were previously selected. You could obviously refine this if you needed, logic might get a bit trickier.